# Der Fall des Infinitivsubjekts

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality

In welchen Fall fällt das Subjekt eines Infinitivs? Das heißt,
welcher von diesen Sätzen ist korrekt?

1. Es ist schwer, ich zu sein.
2. Es ist schwer, mich zu sein.

Comment: @Wolf, https://en.pons.com/translate/latin-german/id+est

Comment: @Wolf, why are you being so rude?

Comment: ["das ist, das heißt"](https://en.pons.com/translate/latin-german/id+est) ist die Aufzählung zweier möglicher Übersetzungen, deshalb steht hinter "das ist" ein Komma. Deine Frage könntest du auf Deutsch z.B. einleiten durch "Anders gefragt, " oder "Mit anderen Worten, "

Comment: @Wolf, https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/d__i_

Answer (score 5):

Im Allgemeinen ist der Kasus nicht davon abhängig, ob ein Infinitiv vorliegt oder nicht, sondern davon, welchen Kasus das vorliegende Verb (und eventuell auftretende Präpositionen) regiert. Beispiele für das Personalpronomen [ich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ich) sind:

1. *Ich* bin. (Nominativ)

   → Es fällt schwer, *ich* zu sein.
2. Erbarmt *meiner*. (Genitiv)

   → Es fällt schwer, sich *meiner* zu erbarmen.
3. Vertraut *mir*. (Dativ)

   → Es fällt schwer, *mir* zu vertrauen.
4. Ich beherrsche *mich*. (Akkusativ)

   → Es fällt schwer, *mich* zu beherrschen.

Da das Subjekt eines Satzes immer im Nominativ steht, gilt das auch für das Wort *ich* im Nebensatz des ersten Beispiels, das dann aber nicht mehr das Subjekt des ganzen Satzes ist:

> Es fällt mir schwer, ich zu sein.

Comment: Das ist nicht als Angriff aufzufassen, aber wurde in letzter Zeit irgendwo abgemacht, dass wir nun die Diskussionen auf Deutsch führen können? Meine letzte Info war, dass auf dieser Seite grundsätzlich Englisch gesprochen wird und nur die Beispiele etc. auf Deutsch geschrieben werden können. Hat da ein Paradigmenwechsel stattgefunden?

Comment: Nur im ersten Beispiele ist das Pronomen Subject des Infinitivs.

Comment: @thymaro, es ist – vermutlich seit Existieren von German StackExchange – so, dass auf Deutsch gestellte Fragen auf Deutsch beantwortet werden (sollten) und auf Englisch gestellte Fragen auf Englisch. Beispielsweise würden sonst meine Eltern gar keine Fragen zu ihrer deutschen Muttersprache stellen können, weil sie gar nicht des Englischen mächtig sind; das wäre absurd.

Comment: @FraeuleinHoeller, ah ,ja genau. Diesen kleinen Hinweis mit dem *Subjekt* habe ich in der Frage überlesen. Ich füge das meiner Antwort noch hinzu.

Comment: Ah! Ich hatte die Aufforderung, doch bitte auf Englisch zu schreiben, dann wohl nur unter englischsprachigen Fragen gelesen. Danke für die Aufklärung.

Comment: Genau: Subjekt immer Nominativ :) Wundert mich, dass eine so komisch gestellte Frage so viel Wertschätzung erfährt.

Comment: .. aber ist das *ich* nach dem Komma wirklich das Subjekt? Glaube ich nicht, siehe z.B. die Struktur von *Es ist schwer, mir zu vertrauen.*

Comment: Ich denke, dass das Wort *sein* ein Prädikatsnomen anbindet, in Form eines Hauptsatzes liefe es auf *Ich bin ich.* hinaus - weniger verwirrend bei *Ich bin Schüler.* - Das Wort hinter bin steht im Nominativ. Ich habe gerade versucht, eine Online-Referenz dazu zu finden, aber der Erfolg war begrenzt...

Comment: Es ist die Frage, ob das *ich* im Beispiel(neben)satz nicht eher das Prädikativum ist. Da aber auch das Prädikativum im Nominativ stehen muss, hat das keine Auswirkung auf den Fall.

Answer (score 2):

Beachte, dass in einem Satz mit "sein" als Prädikat gar kein Objekt steht — sondern ein Prädikativum im Nominativ. Beispiel:

> "Der Staat *(Prädikativum)* bin ich *(Subjekt)*",

woran man auch erkennt, dass das Subjekt manchmal auch bei ungewöhnlicher Wortstellung anhand der Person erkannt werden kann. Entsprechend würde aus meinem Beispiel :

> Es ist schwer, der Staat zu sein.

Gleiches gilt für "werden":

> Es ist schwer, ein guter Arzt zu werden.

Comment: Eigentlich ein hilfreicher Beitrag, aber es fehlt die Antwort auf die gestellte Frage. So ist er genaugenommen nur ein Kommentar.

Answer (score 1):

Richtig ist:

> Es ist schwer, ich zu sein.

Die Voraussetzung der Frage ist falsch: ein erweiterter Infinitiv hat kein Subjekt. Der Infinitiv steht für die Tätigkeit selbst, egal wer sie ausführt. Diese Tätigkeit kann Objekte und andere Ergänzungen haben, aber kein Subjekt:

[Es ist schwer...]

> mich zu hassen
> einen Bären alleine am Morgen zu fangen

Das Verb "sein" steht als Sonderfall nicht mit einem Objekt, sondern einem Prädikativum im Nominativ:

> Peter ist ein Radfahrer.

"Peter" ist das Subjekt, "ein Radfahrer" ist das Prädikativum.

> Es ist schwer, ich zu sein.

Der erweiterte Infinitiv "ich zu sein" hat kein Subjekt, und "ich" ist das Prädikativum.